# BottomSheet always appear in expanded state, it's always in full height. Why is this happen? What's the possible cause of this?

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I want to show a bottom sheet after the user tap on the FAB button. At first, it was working properly but I didn't know why it suddenly started to appear in full height/expanded state mode all the time.

I've tried with all type of bottom sheet listed in the document. It has the same problem.

```
//                _scaffoldKey.currentState
//                    .showBottomSheet((context) => AccountView());
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context, builder: (context) => AccountView());
```

In the AccountView is a ListView, Currently, there's only one item. The bottom sheet height should only be equaled to the height of the ListTile. But it appears in full height instead.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://flutterdoc.com/bottom-sheets-in-flutter-ec05c90453e7)?

Comment: Which channel are you in Flutter? It working fine stable.

Comment: I'm using the stable channel.

Comment: I've checked that one. The thing is that this portion of my code didn't change, and it was working fine when I first put it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shrinkWrap: true, property in ListView or you can put AccountView() in a container and give it height.

Answer (score -1):

Turn out I need to set `shrinkWrap` in the column to true.

```
Column(
shrinkWrap: true,
...
)
```

Comment: Column doesn't have any property named `shrinkWrap`